# Writing a driver for a wireless usb dongle for an AVR microcontroller

Tags: avr

I have an avr micro-controller which supports USB OTG. I also have a wifi usb dongle which connects to the internet. I need to write the required drivers in order to interface this usb dongle with a wifi module. What books would be the right starting point. Could someone please point me in the direction of some good tutorials for achieving this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which AVR model have you got?  Could you post a link, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to get a USB sniffer to be able to sniff the protocol. Otherwise, even if you have a USB stack, you won't know what kind of data to send and receive. Moreover, the driver required to run the USB dongle is likely to be very large, perhaps too large to fit in the AVR micro's flash. I recommend that you pick up a ready made module such as TI's CC3000 or another one.

For USB a good reference is [USB Complete](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1931448086)

[Edit]: I really recommend you look at TI's [CC3000 module](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3000_Wi-Fi_for_MCU). It's throughput can reach 4Mbps, and this is what you should expect from a microcontroller based solution.

Comment: Cant I always use an external flash if the size of the onboard flash is not sufficient

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid External flash memory to run library code from?

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid I don't think AVRs support external flash - they are *microcontrollers* not *microprocessors*

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid: You're going about this the wrong way. That USB WiFi dongle was intended for a computer. Trying to get it to run using a microcontroller has small chances of working, if at all. Why do it? Because you just happen to have a dongle lying around so it's cheap (deceptively)? Get a $15 to $20 WiFi module specifically for microcontrollers and save yourself time. There is little to be gained from this unless you need the learning experience.

Comment: After going through the comments I guess I would go with the CC3000 module. I see some discrepancies in pricing for cc3000. How much do these exactly cost for small volumes (<10)

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid: Or find another module like the ones sold at sparkfun.